# Reading contents of excel file

Tags: java, csv

I am looking for some help with reading contents from a excel file.
Here is the code, I want it to read from the .csv file and 
generate the result for the same.

My error shows

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "companycode"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
    at testgbt.TestGBT.main(TestGBT.java:40)
```

Please help and thanks in advance!!

```
package testgbt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import testgbt.BoostingTree;
import testgbt.BoostingTree.ResultFunction;

public class TestGBT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                String data_name = "C:\\Mihir\\NetBeans\\TestGBT\\data.csv"; 

        Vector<Vector<Double>> x = new Vector<Vector<Double>>();
        Vector<Double>         y = new Vector<Double>();

        try {

                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Mihir\\NetBeans\\TestGBT\\data.csv");

            // -------- load data from the file -------------
            // get object of data input stream
            BufferedReader  b_reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                                InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(data_name))); // buffer

            String read_line;
            while ((read_line = b_reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] str_list = read_line.trim().split(",");

                Vector<Double> buffer_x = new Vector<Double>();
                buffer_x.add(Double.valueOf(str_list[0]));
                x.add(buffer_x);                
                y.add(Double.valueOf(str_list[1]));
            }
            b_reader.close();

            // --------- learn a function of y=f(x) -------
            BoostingTree gbt_ranker = new BoostingTree();
            ResultFunction res_fun = gbt_ranker.gradient_boosting_tree(x, y);

            // --------- save the curve fitting result y=f(x) ------
            FileWriter file_writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Mihir\\NetBeans\\TestGBT\\result.txt");
                        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Mihir\\NetBeans\\TestGBT\\result.csv");

            for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i ++) {
                file_writer.append(String.format("%f,%f,%f\n",
                        x.get(i).get(0),
                        res_fun.get_value(x.get(i)),
                        y.get(i)));
            }

            file_writer.close();

        } catch (Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your question? you cannot understand why string cannot be converted into double?

Comment: i dont know how to make it read string values, the error in the first line... company code Number format excepiton... its still giving errors

Comment: this code reads string values, what is your question?

Comment: Did you try debugging ?

Comment: Can you show us data of .CSV file may be first line atleast?

Comment: From the exception error, seems like the problem comes with your y.add(Double.valueOf(str_list[1])); You should probably check your data.csv file and ctrl + f for "companycode". The error is you're taking the split String which is "companycode" instead of double value. Not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: the data from my .csv file column: companycode,year,fuel,electricity,publictransport,freighttransport,othervehicles,materials,waste,accommodation,other,total.gwp,sumscope1,sumscope2,sumscope3.mandatory,sumscope3.additional,sumscope3.onetime,reduction_percent
C1,2,0,8.4525,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8.4525,0,8.4525,0,0,0,0.291369792

Comment: @user3589469 which column values do you actually want to add to your `Vector`?

Comment: all of the above except for the first one... first row are the headers and first column C1 is just id

Comment: how do i skip the entire first column ?

Answer (score 1):

Does your input CSV have a header row? Remove the header row from your input data or change your code to skip the first line.

You can skip the first row easily by changing this line:

```
String read_line;
```

to this:

```
String read_line = b_reader.readLine();
```

Comment: any help how do i skip the header and first column ? i copied everything into a text file without the headers and column name it works but now i cannot reference back to which company have i got the output for.. –

Comment: oh thank you very much it skips the header... and please suggest how do i skip the first column ? with companycodes ??

Comment: my first column is company code java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C1"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like str_list[1] isn't the data you're looking for.  In fact, it looks like you're trying to convert one of your column headers into a double.  You probably just need to skip past the headers.

Comment: any help how do i skip the header and first column ? i copied everything into a text file without the headers and column name it works but now i cannot reference back to which company have i got the output for..

Comment: The first quick thought that comes to mind is to put a try-catch around the parse call and continue if an exception occurs.  This isn't ideal but it's a thought.  Are the headers the first line that comes in?  If so, you could keep a line count and skip line 0 in your loop.